# make column dataframe become sql query statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using jupyter notebook to access Teradata database.

Assume I have a dataframe

```
Name  Age
 Sam   5
 Tom   6
 Roy   7
```

I want to let the whole column "Name" content become the WHERE condition of a sql query.

```
query = '''select Age
           from xxx
           where Name in (Sam, Tom, Roy)'''
age = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
```

How to format the column so that the whole column can be insert to the sql statement automatically instead of manually paste the column content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `Name` column and insert into the query using f-string:

```
query = f'''select Age
           from xxx
           where Name in ({", ".join(df.Name)})'''

print(query)
select Age
           from xxx
           where Name in (Sam, Tom, Roy)
```